# How to store the result data of an OData query to a JSON model

Tags: sapui5

I have a filtering on an odata query. Is there a way to store the data of the result to another model (JSON). I need the search filter to search the items displayed on the list and not to search for the whole odata model.

```
updateProductsList : function(){
    var filters = [];
    filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("SalesOrganization", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.oSalesOrganization));
    filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("DistributionChannel", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.DistributionChannel));
    filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("ProductID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, this.sFilterPattern));
    filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("CustomerNo", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.oCustomerID));
    this.setDefaultSelection = true;

    this.getList().bindItems("/Products", new sap.ui.xmlfragment("cus.sd.salesorder.create.view.ProductListItemTemplate",this), null,filters);
    console.log("getPRODList0    " + this.getList().bindItems("/Products", new sap.ui.xmlfragment("cus.sd.salesorder.create.view.ProductListItemTemplate",this), null,filters));
var sTitle = this.getView().byId("SOC_MasterListHeaderTitle");
    sTitle.setText(this.oApplicationFacade.getResourceBundle().getText("PRODUCTS_CUST", [this.CustName]));
    this.registerMasterListBind(this.getList());
console.log("getPRODList    " + this.getList().getBinding("items").sPath);
console.log("getPRODList2    " + this.getList().getBindingContext());
console.log("getPRODList3    " + this.getList().getModel());
},
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this. Probably the easiest way is to attach RequestCompleted function to your model that takes a copy of the model's content. You can attach a RequestCompleted function to your model using the Model.attachRequestCompleted function.

While writing the RequestCompleted handler, you could use the oEvents.getParameters() to check the context of the reponse to check whether this request is illegible for your copy-operation. Once you've check, you could just read the model using Model.getProperty("/Products") and copy the data into a JSON model.

Just a quick note: if you copy entries from your OData model to your JSON model, you may be copying references instead of copies. Be aware of this, and clone these entries if necessary.

Comment: Especially the mentioning of "copying an array just copies references to your array, not duplicating it" is important here :)